# Compare Two json in Python and get match

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, match

I have two dict

First

```
Livescore
{'dictA':{'Team_name': 'Turkey - Italy', 'First_team': 6.8, 'Draw': 4.0, 'Second_team': 1.53, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'}}
{'dictA':{'Team_name': 'Wales- Sweden', 'First_team': 3.5, 'Draw': 3.2, 'Second_team': 2.23, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'}}
{'dictA':{'Team_name': 'Spain - Georgia', 'First_team': 1.51, 'Draw': 4.2, 'Second_team': 6.6, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'}}
{'dictA':{'Team_name': 'Belgium - Russia', 'First_team': 1.67, 'Draw': 3.85, 'Second_team': 5.2, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'}}
```

Second one is

```
Flashscore
{'dictA':{'Team_name': 'England- Italy', 'First_team': 1.8, 'Draw': 3.0, 'Second_team': 1.53, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'}}
{'dictA':{'Team_name': 'Wales- Sweden', 'First_team': 3.5, 'Draw': 3.2, 'Second_team': 2.23, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'}}
{'dictA':{'Team_name': 'Spain - Georgia', 'First_team': 1.51, 'Draw': 4.2, 'Second_team': 6.6, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'}}
{'dictA':{'Team_name': 'Russia - Sweden', 'First_team': 1.67, 'Draw': 3.85, 'Second_team': 5.2, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'}}
```

Purpose is to get match data, for example if `England - Italy` is in both (Flashscore and Livescore)get this data.

Which made it difficult for me, The lineup does not match , i mean England - Italy is in 2 Line in Flashscore and in Livescore in 4 and when i try to use `if statement` not get correctly data because line does not match

```
for i in range(len(livescore)):
    if flashscore[i]["Team_name"] == livescore[i]["Team_name"]
    print(livescore[i]["Team_name"])
```

**Need only matching with name** `"Team_name"`

Comment: I don't see `'England - Italy'` in `Livescore`. Also, what are you having - a list of dictionaries?

Comment: it's example , okay then be Turkey - Italy

Comment: What do you mean in Also, what are you having - a list of dictionaries?

Comment: You need to make 2 for loops. One that iterates over livescore and within that one another one that iterates over flashscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Livescore = [
{'Team_name': 'Turkey - Italy', 'First_team': 6.8, 'Draw': 4.0, 'Second_team': 1.53, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'},
{'Team_name': 'Wales- Sweden', 'First_team': 3.5, 'Draw': 3.2, 'Second_team': 2.23, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'},
{'Team_name': 'Spain - Georgia', 'First_team': 1.51, 'Draw': 4.2, 'Second_team': 6.6, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'},
{'Team_name': 'Belgium - Russia', 'First_team': 1.67, 'Draw': 3.85, 'Second_team': 5.2, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'}]

Flashscore = [
{'Team_name': 'England- Italy', 'First_team': 1.8, 'Draw': 3.0, 'Second_team': 1.53, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'},
{'Team_name': 'Wales- Sweden', 'First_team': 3.5, 'Draw': 3.2, 'Second_team': 2.23, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'},
{'Team_name': 'Spain - Georgia', 'First_team': 1.51, 'Draw': 4.2, 'Second_team': 6.6, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'},
{'Team_name': 'Russia - Sweden', 'First_team': 1.67, 'Draw': 3.85, 'Second_team': 5.2, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'}]


    

    def get_match(data_1, data_2, line_name):
        data1_set = set(data1[line_name] for data1 in data_1)
        result_list = []
        for date2 in data_2:
            if date2[line_name] in data1_set:
                result_list.append(date2[line_name])
        return result_list

    print(get_match(Livescore, Flashscore, 'Team_name'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to find the correct item in both lists.

```py
for item in flashscore:
    for other in livescore:
        if item["Team_name"] == other["Team_name"]:
            print(item, other)
```

This is woefully inefficient, though. A better arrangement would be to create a dict of dicts for each.

```py
flashindex = {x["Team_name"]: x for x in flashscore}
liveindex = {x["Team_name"]: x for x in livescore}
```

Now it's easy to find all items which are in both:

```py
for item in liveindex.keys():
    if item in flashindex:
        print(flashindex[item], liveindex[item])
```

There are several further variations you could do, but hopefully this should at least get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is to build sets of the team names for both Livescore and Flashscore and then get the [intersection](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp) of both.

```
live_score_names = set(item['Team_name'] for item in live_score_items)
flash_score_names = set(item['Team_name'] for item in flash_score_items)
intersection_names = live_score_names.intersection(flash_score_names)
```

you can now filter the items in live_score_items and flash_score_names depending on your need. You know that names in intersection_names exist in both.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the dict so that it contains something like:

`'Teams':{'England','Turkey'}`

Set makes more sense to compare

Answer (score 0):

```
def prepare_score_dict(sample_list):
    result = {}
    for item in sample_list:
        result[item.pop('Team_name')] = item
    return result

livescore_dict = prepare_score_dict(Livescore)
flashscore_dict = prepare_score_dict(Flashscore)

for key in livescore_dict.keys():
    if key in flashscore_dict.keys():
        print(key)
```

try it.

Comment: Thanks work! can you change your code for my code ? i update it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have pandas you can try the following:

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd

df_livescore = pd.DataFrame([{'Team_name': 'Turkey - Italy', 'First_team': 6.8, 'Draw': 4.0, 'Second_team': 1.53, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'},
{'Team_name': 'Wales - Sweden', 'First_team': 3.5, 'Draw': 3.2, 'Second_team': 2.23, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'},
{'Team_name': 'Spain - Georgia', 'First_team': 1.51, 'Draw': 4.2, 'Second_team': 6.6, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'},
{'Team_name': 'Belgium - Russia', 'First_team': 1.67, 'Draw': 3.85, 'Second_team': 5.2, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'}])

df_flashscore = pd.DataFrame([{'Team_name': 'England- Italy', 'First_team': 1.8, 'Draw': 3.0, 'Second_team': 1.53, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'},
{'Team_name': 'Wales - Sweden', 'First_team': 3.5, 'Draw': 3.2, 'Second_team': 2.23, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'},
{'Team_name': 'Spain - Georgia', 'First_team': 1.51, 'Draw': 4.2, 'Second_team': 6.6, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'},
{'Team_name': 'Russia - Sweden', 'First_team': 1.67, 'Draw': 3.85, 'Second_team': 5.2, 'Country_name': 'EURO 2020', 'Liga': 'Test_liga'}])
```

**Code:**

```
df_livescore.merge(df_flashscore, on=['Team_name'])
```

**Output:**

```
#          Team_name  First_team_x  ...  Country_name_y     Liga_y
# 0   Wales - Sweden          3.50  ...       EURO 2020  Test_liga
# 1  Spain - Georgia          1.51  ...       EURO 2020  Test_liga
# [2 rows x 11 columns]
```